# Unicode conversion changes estimated row count

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is generating a bad execution plan, and I traced it to the fact that doing a Unicode conversion changes the estimated row count in the execution plan.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(       
    BusinessUnit VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CustomerId VARCHAR(20)
)

ALTER TABLE Orders ADD PRIMARY KEY(BusinessUnit, OrderNumber)
```

I inserted a bunch of test data into the table, and ran `UPDATE STATISTICS Orders`.  `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(Orders, PK__Orders__4F8C6988304CED14)` shows me this result:

[image]

Now, if I run the query

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE BusinessUnit = 'USA'
```

One of the steps is a Clustered Index Seek on Orders, which has an estimated number of rows of 735

However, if I add a Unicode conversion like this

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE BusinessUnit = N'USA'
```

I get an estimated number of rows of 410.5.

What causes the estimated number of rows to change when I do the Unicode conversion?  Can indexes on non-Unicode fields not be used with a Unicode clause?  When I have some larger queries that are joining several tables, adding a unicode conversion on a single field in the WHERE clause causes a significant change in the query execution plan, which makes the query's running time increase by an order of magnitude.

Comment: If your `BusinessUnit` column is of type `VARCHAR` then why are you comparing it to a value of type `NVARCHAR` in the first place?

Comment: "Can indexes on non-Unicode fields not be used with a Unicode clause?" - It depends on collation but even if the collation allows it you should avoid this as it can have other effects - as you have noticed.

Comment: This came up because Entity Framework does the Unicode conversion by default.  I solved it by using `IsUnicode(false)` for my column mapping, but I want to know what causes this behavior.

Comment: @BenRubin, not only does the conversion affect row count estimates, the expression isn't sargable so an index on the column cannot be used efficiently (scan instead of seek). Using Unicode expressions against a varchar column is very bad for performance.

Comment: @DanGuzman this is collation dependent whether it will force a scan.

Comment: @MartinSmith, right, I should have said "might not" instead of "cannot" in my comment. The scan occurs with legacy SQL collations, which are commonly used in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, a single Unicode character is 16 bits, while a non-Unicode character is 8 bits. Since statistics are only kept for the data type in the table, there are no good statistics for comparing them with Unicode values.

When the optimizer tries to optimize the query for a varchar <==> varchar lookup, it uses the statistics to both decide the best query plan, and to estimate the number of rows returned.

But when it tries to look up a varchar data item based on a non-varchar value, it has to make educated guesses about how the different data type may effect the **average** lookup. I doubt the optimizer would directly analyze the values in the lookup string to see how many are in the current non-Unicode character set, so it probably uses some pre-programmed statistical value based on, oh, perhaps your default character set, and perhaps your country code, to determine adjustment factors as to the number of rows that will be returned.

Basically, when comparing apples to oranges and expecting matches, you may have to guess a bit as to how many matches to expect.

Answer (score 1):

The estimate is based on All Density instead of the histogram because the value is unknown at compile time (due to implicit conversion). The All Density value of 0.5 times 821 rows is 410.5.